# Increase Maximum Upload size of phpMyAdmin in CWP Admin Panel

Tags: php, upload, limit, filesize

My name is Steve, i am running your good CWP on my site, unfortunately i am not able to change the maximum Upload file size on phpMyAdmin,

I have done some changes according to google search results, but problem is it still shows 64MB, please guide us how and where the code should be changed for root and users of domains.

i am using 
CWP version: 0.9.8.389
Php 5

[Increase Maximum Upload size of phpMyAdmin - Screenshot Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9iUX.jpg)

i have already tried method :: Try this solution:- https://blog.bullten.com/increase-maximum-upload-size-of-phpmyadmin-in-centos-web-panel-cwp/

also but nothing good in results. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

i checked the link you posted but it doesn't mention the most important part, which is after changing the value in the php.ini file save the file and restart the sever, you have to restart the server other wise the changes wouldn't take place.

also if you have SSH access try these command

```
$ locate php.ini
```

this will show you were the file is located the access the file
for example `$sudo nano etc/php.ini`

and make sure that those valuse are like the following

```
upload_max_filesize = 2M 
post_max_size = 8M
```

you can always modify it then save and restart the server (`$ sudo apachectl restart`)

Comment: another way is to set the max upload file on a .htaccess file on the root directory

Comment: Can you please tell me how to write this .htaccess file and where to place it

Comment: Thanks Dear issue has been solved by your query, if anyone else also have issue on CWP Panel can ask to also how to fix that :)